# Discord.js: Cannot read property "roles" of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Ive been working on a bot, and I am trying to get it to create a role and add it, it was working before, but now it is no longer working.

Here is the code:

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  var member = message.mentions.members.first();
  var sender = message.author;
  var guild = message.guild;
  var name = (message.author.username + "'s party")
  var role = sender.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === message.author.username + "'s party");
  // sender.roles.add(role);


  if (typeof role === undefined) {
    let newRole = guild.roles.create({
      data: {
        name: name,
        color: 'BLUE',
      },
      reason: 'Partee',
    })
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.error);

      member.roles.add(newRole);
      message.channel.send("Your party has been created!")
  } else {
    member.roles.add(newRole);
    message.channel.send("You have been added to your party!")
  }
}
```

I dont know why it is going wrong. here is the error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Comment: What message are you sending to the bot when running into the error? Also, feel free to [edit] your question to change the title or add details.

Comment: the prefix is =, and the command name is party

Comment: You probably need to use `guild` instead of `sender.guild` in line 6.

Comment: Same error 101arrowz

Comment: As far as I know is that `message.author` doesn't have a `guild` property

Comment: How would i go about correctly writing this though?

Answer (score 0):

The `message.author` doesn't have a `guild` method, so calling this will return `undefined`. To make a role and give it to both author and mentioned user, I would do something like this for example:

```js
if(message.author.bot === true) return;
if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

const name = (message.author.username + "'s party");
const member = message.mentions.members.first();

if(member) {
    const authorUser = message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id);
    // Find the role first
    const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === name);
    if(!role) {
        // The role has not be found, create a new one.
        // Create the new role and give it to the person
        // Discord v12: { data: { name: "name", reason: "new role", ...properties } }
        // Discord v13: { name: "name", reason: "new role", ...properties }
        message.guild.roles.create({
            data: {
                name: name,
                color: "BLUE",
            },
            reason: "The party has been started "
        }).then(RoleCreated => {
            authorUser.roles.add(RoleCreated)
                .then(() => member.roles.add(RoleCreated))
                .then(() => message.channel.send("PARTY HAS BEEN CREATED! LET'S GET THIS PARTY STARTED! "))
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error.message);
                });
        });
    }else{
        // Role exists, give it to the mentioned user
        member.roles.add(role).then(() => message.channel.send("WELCOME TO MY PARTY! LET'S GET THIS PARTY STARTED! ")).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error.message);
        });
    }
}
```

`!` You might need to adjust the code to fit with your framework. I have tested this on Discord V13. Should work on V12 as well. Also note that if a user changes it's username, a new role will be created, so your server might get some ghost roles.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that message.author returns the user that sent the message. You would need the member. The member object returns more details about the user, by giving information on the user's position in a server/guild.

Just change the value of `sender` to `message.member`.

Example:

```
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
  var member = message.mentions.members.first();
  var sender = message.member;
  var guild = message.guild;
  var name = (message.author.username + "'s party")
  var role = sender.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === message.author.username + "'s party");
  // sender.roles.add(role);


  if (typeof role === undefined) {
    let newRole = guild.roles.create({
      data: {
        name: name,
        color: 'BLUE',
      },
      reason: 'Partee',
    })
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.error);

      member.roles.add(newRole);
      message.channel.send("Your party has been created!")
  } else {
    member.roles.add(newRole);
    message.channel.send("You have been added to your party!")
  }
}
```

Hopefully that works!